# Scope of user ID uniqueness in Google OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, google-oauth

We are adding user login to our mobile applications (plural) using Google OAuth 2.0. Each app will have its own Client ID which will be defined in a separate Google cloud project because we want each app to have its own login consent screen with customized tile, logo etc. However we are storing the user IDs for all the apps in a single DB table.

Consider the following scenario: 2 different users - Alice and Bob, where Alice signed in to `MyApp1` and Bob signed in to `MyApp2` (each app defined in a different Google project under the same GCP account). Is it possible for both, Alice and Bob, get assigned the same user ID `X`? Or is it possible that Alice will get assigned user ID `X` when signed into `MyApp1` and get user ID `Y` when signed into `MyApp2`?

Assuming that Google fully adhere to OpenID Connect standard. The OpenID standard says:

> sub
> REQUIRED. Subject Identifier. A locally unique and never reassigned identifier within the
> Issuer for the End-User, which is intended to be consumed by the Client...

What does "A locally unique and never reassigned" mean?

TIA

Comment: Remember Alice and bob are going to have to login to both apps. Tokens returned will only work for the app that hey were created for.   If you get their profile infomraiton Google returns their user id to you you could use that as your user id and then have a link between the apps.

Answer (score 1):

Alice and Bob will get different user ids from Google Auth, which are like GUIDs, and your APIs will receive them in the subject claim. This value remains constant even if the user changes their name or email.

The sub claim will be the same across all apps, though it could be possible in some advanced scenarios to use [pairwise identifiers](https://forum.forgerock.com/2018/02/enhancing-user-privacy-openid-connect-pairwise-identifiers/amp/) where the sub is different per app. This is usually best avoided though.

**WHAT MANY COMPANIES DO**

In most real world systems you then need to look up the user in your own data after login, to access the user's application data. You need to map the sub value to a database row. See my post on [User Data Management](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data/) for some thoughts on how to handle this.